# Updating earliest record in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a problem at the moment where I would like to update the earliest entry for a job in my table called Service_Log_Temp with duplicate = 'No' and the rest with duplicate = 'Yes'

Here is my table at the moment:

[image: http://s15.postimage.org/gulifcaiz/Current_Table.jpg]

So I would like a script which looks at the K_B_Job_No (you'll see I have 2 different jobs listed here) and updates the earliest entry based on L1_GA_SR_Creation_Date & L2_B_Start_time_Of_Activity with Duplicate = 'No' and the rest with Duplicate = 'Yes'.

This is how it should look:

[image: http://s14.postimage.org/h7zx5xgj5/Desired_Table.jpg]

Any ideas?

Comment: Which data base system are you using?

Comment: I can see why 2012-11-08 11:00 is a duplicate, but why is 2012-11-09 08:30 a duplicate? Why is 2012-11-13 13:58 not a duplicate?

Comment: The first three jobs have the same K_B_Job_No 28862103, whereas the four last have another K_B_Job_No  (28886103) (I had to look quite carefully at the tables to see the difference..)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select key_service,k_r_job_no,L1_GA_SR_Creation_Date,L2_B_Start_time_Of_Activity,
   case 
    when (select min(L1_GA_SR_Creation_Date) and min(L2_B_Start_time_Of_Activity)
       then 'No'
      else 'Yes'
  end as Duplicate
from Service_Log_Temp
group by k_r_job_no
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with a as (select K_B_Job_No, min(L1_GA_SR_Creation_Date + cast(L2_B_Start_time_Of_Activity as datetime)) as dttime from Service_Log_Temp
group by K_B_Job_No)
select key_service,K_B_Job_No,L1_GA_SR_Creation_Date,L2_B_Start_time_Of_Activity, 
(case when
(select dttime from a where a.K_B_Job_No=b.K_B_Job_No)=(L1_GA_SR_Creation_Date + cast(L2_B_Start_time_Of_Activity as datetime))
then 'NO' else 'YES' end) as Duplicate
from Service_Log_Temp b
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work in postgres, where the concatenation is || - you must change that to whatever is the concatenation in your system

background: To find the time for the first run of each job :

```
select k_r_job_no,min( L1_GA_SR_Creation_Date+L2_B_Start_time_Of_Activity) from
service_log_temp
group by k_r_job_no
```

The problem is just that we cannot get the ids out from this query...

but we can use this as a subquery. As it is normally not possible to get more than one row out of a subquery, we have to do a concatenation to get the right time for each job: (you may need to do a type cast to get the concatenation to work)

```
select key_service from service_log_temp where 
   k_r_job_no||L1_GA_SR_Creation_Date+L2_B_Start_time_Of_Activity in( 
     select k_r_job_no||min( L1_GA_SR_Creation_Date+L2_B_Start_time_Of_Activity) 
       from service_log_temp
        group by k_r_job_no
     )
```

This can be rewritten as an update:

```
update service_log_temp set Duplicate='Yes' where 
   k_r_job_no||L1_GA_SR_Creation_Date+L2_B_Start_time_Of_Activity in( 
     select k_r_job_no||min( L1_GA_SR_Creation_Date+L2_B_Start_time_Of_Activity) 
       from service_log_temp
        group by k_r_job_no
     )
```

And then afterwards

```
 update service_log_temp set Duplicate='No' where Duplicate is null
```

(or, use "case" as SRIRAM proposed if you want to have it in one query)